# Variável dentro de aspas - Angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estou construindo um APP hibrido com ionic, este se utiliza do Angular e eu não sou muito familiarizado com JS.

A questão é que eu preciso inserir um video do Youtube no plicativo e esbarrei na seguinte questão: O link do video vem de uma API externa e portando preciso que seja inserido no código por uma variável e, no entanto, não consigo fazer funcionar.

Segue um código que exemplifica o problema, onde vídeo não aparece no iframe.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>AngularJs</title>
</head>
<body ng-app>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<p>Link: {{link}}</p>
</div>

<iframe src="{{ link }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" width="560" height="315" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>

<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
function Ctrl($scope){
  $scope.link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl3aJms0xGQ";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

O mesmo ocorre neste caso:

```html
<button id="encontrar-button1" class="button button-balanced  button-block icon-left ion-plus-circled" onclick="window.open('http://www.site.com/pagina/{{ url }}/{{ .id }}/', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">Link</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

No caso de embedar videos do Youtube eu recomendo você usar uma diretiva para isto... exemplo: 
Diretiva :

```
app.directive('youtubeIframe', function($sce) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: { videoid:'=' },
        replace: true,
        template: '<div style="height:400px;"><iframe width="420" height="315" src="{{url}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.$watch('videoid', function (value) {
               if (value) {
                   scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + value);
               }
            });
        }
      };
    });
```

E no seu HTML é só adicionar a diretiva passando o ID do video que voce quer embedar:

```
<div youtube-iframe videoid="CcFxvOBohvM"></div>
```

Exemplo do codigo:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.controller('Ctrl',function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.videoId = 'Hl3aJms0xGQ';
  
  $scope.open = function() {
    $window.open('https://www.google.com','', 'width=500,height=500')
  }

});
app.directive('youtubeIframe', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      videoid: '='
    },
    replace: true,
    template: '<div style="height:400px;"><iframe width="420" height="315" src="{{url}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.$watch('videoid', function(value) {
        if (value) {
          scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + value);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <title>AngularJs</title>
</head>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <button ng-click="open()">Link</button>
    <div youtube-iframe videoid="videoId"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Funcionou para o vídeo. E quanto ao segundo caso, do window.open? Obrigado por responder Jhonny.

Comment: Eu atualizei o codigo mas o Stackoverflow está bloqueando o popup. Aqui tem o mesmo exemplo no  [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypvxj1ud/). Mas se a sua intenção é fazer uma janela "popup" você poderia tentar trabalhar com modals isto evitaria problemas futuros com bloqueadores de popup -> [Modals Ionic](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/making-modals/)